# How to remove a symbol from this footer?

Tags: html, css, sass

My goal is to make a footer like this one below

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: footer example

Is there a way to remove the dot symbol from the last list selector using this way?

```css
            li {
                list-style: none;
                display: inline-block;

                &:last-child{
                    content: "" !important;
                }

                &:after {
                    content: " ·";
                }


                a {
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: #666666;
                    padding: 7px 10px;
                }
            }
```

```html
    <ul class="footer-nav">
        <li><a href="">Legal</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Privacy</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Cookies</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Thank you

Comment: You didn't include the link to your Example Image

Comment: Try :not(:last-child)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain the `:last-child` and `:after` pseudo-selectors together to create a selector that only targets the last `:after` pseudo-element. From here, you simply need to override the existing `content` with an empty string. Note that the selector `li:last-child:after` **already** has more [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than `li:after`, so this will *automatically* override the dot, and should be all you need:

```
li:last-child:after {
  content: "";
}
```

In terms of SASS, this would be:

```
li {
  &:last-child {
    &:after {
      content: "";
    }
  }
}
```

This can be seen in the following:

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

li:last-child {
  content: "" !important;
}

li:after {
  content: " ·";
}

li:last-child:after {
  content: "";
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666666;
  padding: 7px 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="footer-nav">
  <li><a href="">Legal</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Privacy</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Cookies</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

[image: Override]

Comment: Thanks! Now i know i can cnain pseudo-selectors! :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `:after` in your last-child selector. This should work:

```
li:last-child:after{
    content: "";
}
```